# Weird behaviour by System.IO.Path.Combine()

Tags: c#, .net

`Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\\some\\path\\", "this\\folder\\"));` when run in [microsoft's try-dotnet page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/try-dotnet), returns `C:\some\path\/this\folder\`.

I expect it to return `C:\some\path\this\folder\`.

How to fix this?

**EDIT:** In [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/), however, I get the expected result. But I am worried because the official try-dotnet returns unexpected result.

Comment: I suspect it's a UNIX 'thing' with the web page, since the forward slash has been added between the 2 strings. How ironic would that be!

Comment: You need to use the share feature on .net fiddle

Comment: @MitchWheat, I guess you are right, I am getting the expected result when run in Windows Visual Studio as well.

Comment: Since the path separator is platform-dependent you should not hard code it to backslash or forward slash, but consistently use the Path methods to construct or dissect paths.

Comment: No: `System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\\some\\path\\", "this\\folder\\")`. Yes: `System.IO.Path.Combine("C:", "some", "path", "this", "folder")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0

The problem with [try-dotnet](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/try-dotnet) is that it is Unix-based system.

```
string[] paths = {@"d:\archives", "2001", "media", "images"};
string fullPath = Path.Combine(paths);
Console.WriteLine(fullPath);            

paths = new string[] {@"d:\archives\", @"2001\", "media", "images"};
fullPath = Path.Combine(paths);
Console.WriteLine(fullPath); 

paths = new string[] {"d:/archives/", "2001/", "media", "images"};
fullPath = Path.Combine(paths);
Console.WriteLine(fullPath); 
// The example displays the following output if run on a Windows system:
//    d:\archives\2001\media\images
//    d:\archives\2001\media\images
//    d:/archives/2001/media\images
//
// The example displays the following output if run on a Unix-based system:
//    d:\archives/2001/media/images
//    d:\archives\/2001\/media/images
//    d:/archives/2001/media/images
```